# piwik not working in HTTPS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, matomo

I install piwik on sub domain `analytics.mydomain.com/piwik` [other VPS], and add javascript code in `head` tag in HTML on my website [HTTPS].

I worked laravel 5.3 framework.

This code:

```
<!-- Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _paq = _paq || [];
    // tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView"
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
    _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
    (function() {
        var u="//analytics.mydomain.com/piwik/";
        _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
        _paq.push(['setSiteId', '1']);
        var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
    })();
</script>
<!-- End Analytics Code -->
```

This code working in localhost but not work on the server.

My website just working with `HTTPS`.

How to issue?

Comment: What are the symptoms of it not working? For example: are you getting an error? Is it not making calls at all? Are visits not showing in Piwik? Related question: do you have HTTPS on the Piwik server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the page is HTTPS, all assets - images, CSS, JavaScript, etc. - must also be HTTPS in modern browsers. Attempts to include HTTP assets will fail with a "mixed content" error.

You will need an SSL certificate for `analytics.mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue awhile back. Forcing the url to https like below (in line 8) fixed it for me. I can't promise it will work for you, but it is worth a try.

```
<!-- Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _paq = _paq || [];
    // tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView"
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
    _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
    (function() {
        var u="https://analytics.mydomain.com/piwik/";
        _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
        _paq.push(['setSiteId', '1']);
        var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
    })();
</script>
<!-- End Analytics Code -->
```

Comment: Hi, Don't install SSL in analytics.mydomain.com and don't work HTTPS.

Comment: @mySun Well, you'll need SSL for it. You can't use HTTP assets on a HTTPS page.

Answer (score 1):

[Your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43840596/piwik-not-working-in-https#comment74802538_43875881) suggests you don't have SSL on `analytics.mydomain.com`, which means you need to force the code to *not* use HTTPS:

```
<!-- Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _paq = _paq || [];
    // tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView"
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
    _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
    (function() {
        var u="http://analytics.mydomain.com/piwik/";
        _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
        _paq.push(['setSiteId', '1']);
        var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
    })();
</script>
<!-- End Analytics Code -->
```

When you use [protocol-relative URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#prurl) (like `//` without `http:` or `http:`), it tells the browser to call Piwik with the same protocol that the original page is in. If you don't have SSL on the Piwik server, it can't receive HTTPS requests (it will give a certificate error if it's even running on port 443).

Comment: HTTP requests will be blocked if the page this code is on is HTTPS.